# Import JSON Data in grafana with jwt authentication

Tags: json, authentication, jwt, grafana, analytics

I'm planning to create a grafana Dashboard to monitor my web app performance.
Im collecting analytics of the websites landingpage with my selfhosted [umami](https://umami.is/) instance.
Umami offers an REST api to read website stats. The [documentation](https://umami.is/docs/authentication) says that authentification with the api is achieved by getting an jwt token and pass it in the http header to retrieve data from endpoints.

The JSON [plugins](https://grafana.com/grafana/plugins/simpod-json-datasource/) in Grafana seem to only work with basic http auth.

I'm expecting to store the jwt token and pass ist afterwards in the request. In best case the auth process  is automated before each fetch. How can i achieve to fetch data with jwt token authorization?